# OpenCL.jl CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

Tags: opencl, julia, nvidia

This week I've faced a very popular error: `CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR` using `OpenCL.jl`. However nothing found in google helps to overcome it. I've tried complete reinstalling CUDA, using different versions of drivers etc. 
What's strange: `deviceQuery` CUDA tool works as expected, while `julia` has that error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I have been looking at CUDA but not at OpenCL.

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

shows all the truth:

```
ii  nvidia-375                                      375.39-0ubuntu5                             amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.39
ii  nvidia-375-dev                                  375.26-0ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604             375.51-1                                    amd64        nvidia-driver-local repository configuration files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                 375.51-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-375                           375.51-0ubuntu1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.4                                       amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 375.51-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Here you can see I've had different versions of nvidia drivers and `nvidia-opencl-icd-375`. Installing correct version of it with

```
sudo apt install nvidia-opencl-icd-375=375.39-0ubuntu5
```

made it finally work.

For some reason I can't yet install latest (375.51) version of nvidia drivers, there are some dependency problems with `xorg-video-abi`. But that's already enough for me.